# How to save ggplot generated graph as image in streamlit python

Tags: python, streamlit

I have plotted a ggplot graph. now i want to provide the download graph as image option in my streamlit app. Any idea how to do that.

This is my ggplot code.

```
 A = A + geom_line(data = pred1,mapping = aes(x = 'time',y = 'U_CI'),color = "red",linetype = "dotted",size = 1.3)\
                            +geom_line(data = pred2,mapping = aes(x = 'time',y = 'U_CI'),color = "blue",linetype = "dotted",size = 1.3)\
                            +geom_line(data = pred3,mapping = aes(x = 'time',y = 'U_CI'),color = "green",linetype = "dotted",size = 1.3)\
                            +geom_line(data = pred1,mapping = aes(x = 'time',y = 'L_CI'),color = "red",linetype = "dotted",size = 1.3)\
                            +geom_line(data = pred2,mapping = aes(x = 'time',y = 'L_CI'),color = "blue",linetype = "dotted",size = 1.3)\
                            +geom_line(data = pred3,mapping = aes(x = 'time',y = 'L_CI'),color = "green",linetype = "dotted",size = 1.3)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what programming language you are talking about? Meaning, if you're trying to call R code (i.e. the "real" ggplot2) from Python, it's not going to be a trivial example.

If your example is using a Python package that happens to have the same syntax as the R package, then it's a much easier problem.

Comment: I am working in python

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions come equipped with a download function:

```
pip install --upgrade streamlit
```

```
with open("flower.png", "rb") as file:
     btn = st.download_button(
             label="Download image",
             data=file,
             file_name="flower.png",
             mime="image/png"
           )
```

But I would recommend using **plotly** which is also supported by streamlit and it also has a "download as ..." button on each graph. --> https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/

[image]